# What does limit performance of scp?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, scp

I've two Debian Linux machine connected via 1 Gbit LAN. I can measure this with a raw HTTP file transfer with `wget` which gets around 100MB/s in either direction.

When I now use `scp`, the maximum without compression I get is around **15MB/s**. Enabling compression with the `-C` flag gives me, dependent on the contents, up to **50MB/s**.

Still, there's a **lot** bandwidth wasted here it seems. I didn't bother for a long time until I really had to think about some very large logfile transfers and just realized how oddly slow `scp` is. It's naturally for me to use `scp`, even in company environment, because all infrastructure is set up for it.

What limits the performance of scp that much? Is it CPU bound because of the encryption? When I use `htop` it seems it doesn't make use of multicore CPUs, just one of four CPUs is maxed.

Is there a way to increase the throughput? I've HTTP servers and samba available, but for moving files between Linux machines I usually just use SSH, that's the way I grew up with it. But this now makes me think about it, seems I need to consider other ways of transfer for large amounts of data.

HTTP is only used for specific application in PHP/Java/whatever and samba is used for some special reasons we need access from Windows machines.

Comment: The answer from JooMing worked for me fabulous, but `-C` option for compression made it slower (21MB/s instead of 112MB/s). So please take care with `-C`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably it's the encryption. You can try scp with different ciphers, for example:

```
scp -c arcfour src dest
```

Check ssh_config manual page for available Ciphers. RC4 (arcfour) is a fast cipher, but probably not as secure as some alternatives.

Comment: It should be noted that the use of **RC4** is **not secure** and the communications can be broken easily.

Answer (score 6):

Part of it may have to do with the internal implementation of OpenSSH. Take a look at [HPN-SSH](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/hpn-ssh/) for a decent explanation for one reason for the bottlenecks, and patches to OpenSSH that can resolve it (if you're willing to patch and rebuild from source).