# Why is scp with compression slower than without?

Tags: ssh, scp, file-transfer

I needed to transfer a 20 GB [KVM](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/KVM) vdisk file, storing the root filesystem of a CentOS 6.5 VM, from one lab server to another. The large file size and the fact that I had once compressed such a vdisk file to a few hundred mega-bytes made me instinctively enable compression with `scp` but I was surprised to see a rather low transfer speed. Then I tried `bzip2` in combination with `ssh` and `cat` and was startled. Here is the summary of methods and average throughput.

- `scp -C vm1-root.img root@192.168.161.62:/mnt/vdisks/`, 11 MB/s.
- `bzip2 -c vm1-root.img | ssh -l root 192.168.161.62 "bzip2 -d -c > /mnt/vdisks/vm1-root.img"`, 5 MB/s. This even lower result prompted searching on the Net.
- `scp -c arcfour -C vm1-root.img root@192.168.161.62:/mnt/vdisks/`, 13 MB/s. This use of `-c arcfour` as was suggested in [one answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/207164/what-does-limit-performance-of-scp) on serverfault. It hardly helped. Finally, I disabled compression.
- `scp vm1-root.img root@192.168.161.62:/mnt/vdisks/`, 23 MB/s.

Shouldn't compression have been faster?

---

After receiving the `ssh(1)` man page tip from @sven, I tried a couple alternative methods of file transfer not involving compression, both with better results.

- `cat vm1-root.img  | ssh -l root 192.168.161.62 "cat  > /mnt/vdisks/vm1-root.img"`, 26 MB/s.
- `nc -l 5678 > /mnt/vdisks/vm1-root.img` on the receiver and `nc 192.168.161.62 5678 < vm1-root.img` on the transmitter, 40 MB/s. The port  `5678` is an arbitrary one that was available.

Using `nc` turned out to be the fastest copying method!

In the past, `scp -C` has worked very well whenever I thought it would. For example, when transferring syslogs (`/var/log/messages*`) of few GBs in size. An uncompressed transfer rate of few hundred KB/s would increase to 1-2 MB/s. This example does fall in the case of a slow connection as has been pointed out in the man page.

I have a case where, a newly created vdisk image for a 20 GB partition has a compressed size of just 200 MB. With a transfer rate of about 25 MB/s, we could do the copying in just 8 seconds instead of over 13 minutes! Clearly, `scp` without compression is inefficient in this case and `scp -C` is even worse.

I guess, the main lesson learned here is that, `scp -C` should be thought of as only being a convenience. If a file can be significantly compressed, then it is better to first compress it on the source, transfer the compressed form and finally decompress on the destination. Tools that do the compression and decompression quickly (e.g. [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/)) will be of greater help.

Comment: ssh compression uses zlib (DEFLATE), so bzip2 being even slower is expected. gzip should be comparable. As for why the `cat` tip is faster... I have no idea. Maybe that's why they kicked scp away when sftp appeared.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting `man ssh` (which is the base used by `scp`):

> Compression is desirable on modem lines and other slow connections, but will only slow down things on fast networks.

The problem is that compressing the data takes more time then just sending it over the network.

Comment: He was specifically asking why the transfer rate was lower, but I suspect ssh actually calculates this by dividing data size by the total time the whole operation takes, and not separating the part where it compresses data and the part where it copies the data over the network.

Comment: @Ernie: If you can transmit data with a speed of 20 MB/s, and the system can only deliver it with 15 MB/s because the compression is so slow, it will be transmitted with only 15 MB/s. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Ernie: The transfer rate printed by `scp` includes the time spent in compressing/decompressing. Reported values would appear surprising if this were not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Also, on top of compression, nc gets the best rate because it doesn't encrypt, either.  And non-lossy compression relies on finding redundant sections of the data, which when done at the network level you can look at a maximum of [buffer-size] bytes where when done with the entire file first, it's [file-size] bytes within which to hunt and crunch duplicate byte sentences.

Also for moving disk images you should use a filesystem-aware tool like ntfsclone/partclone because even compression can't beat just plain skipping the unallocated blocks - your transfer rate is infinite if you don't have to transfer any data.  Also don't forget to destroy the swap and hibernation files on a windows partition or you're copying junk it will just throw away and recreate anyway.